# f77 code in gfortran - library call

Tags: libraries, gfortran, g77

I've inherited an old f77/g77 program from a previous researcher, but have very little Fortran experience. I've worked through most of the syntax conversion in the file, but I'm running into an issue where the old file calls a (deprecated?) library known as [libstr](http://www.ccl.net/cca/software/SOURCES/FORTRAN/string-library/libstr/string.shtml). I can't seem to find reference to this in any current gfortran documentation (though I'm not sure I'm looking in the right places, either). What I'd like to know is if there is a way to avoid calling the `Union` and  `flostr` functions, and instead just output the values directly in the file.

The relevant portion of code is here:

```
if (mod(ntime,nout) .eq. 0) then

ndec = 1
call flostr(t,str1,ndec)
call Union('signal_t=',str1,str2)
call Union('lineshapeSPConD_t=',str1,str3)
open(7,file = str3,STATUS ='unknown')
```

I suppose that either figuring out how to install the library (I tried running the makefile, and gfortran looks at /usr/bin in its search path), or being able to replace the functions would solve the problem. I'm using gfortran 4.8 installed from Homebrew on OS X 10.8.3.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I succeeded in making the code compile by including the library in the gfortran compile, but now running the output program results in a string of errors…

The output errors are:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous 
arithmetic operation.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x1470e91c2
#1  0x1470e998e
#2  0x7fff92330949
#3  0x10421642e
#4  0x104217472
[1]    18171 floating point exception  ./Lineshape_thick_SP_New.x
```

Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Change your compile line to include symbols and debug information so that the stack trace will be more useful.  It's unfortunate that you have the code and no makefiles - maybe a little more searching from the previous researchers machine will yield this information also?

Comment: Unfortunately, the previous researcher was bad at organization… and the machine has since been dismantled. Supposedly, it was backed up to our server, but wading through the morass is often a fruitless search.